# How to make an icon open in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website and in the navigation bar in the header I have the logo on the left and the links to the other pages on the right, and when the browser is resized to less than 600px all the links are supposed to go into an icon but the logo remains.

When I click the icon the formatting of the links and the icon changes to the default settings and I want the links to display one after the other below each other [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6H8u.png) (example taken from www.W3Schools.com).

I hope someone could help me with this error.

Thank you.

```
<div class="slideshow_nav">
          <div class="navbar-wlogo">
            <img src="/Users/yanikwick/Documents/canvas_website/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo "width = "175px">
            <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
              <a href="/html/contact">CONTACT</a>
              <a href="/html/about">ABOUT</a>
              <a href="/html/portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
              <a href="/html/">HOME</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:30px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </nav>
          </div>
```

This is the html for the navigation bar.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
  }
```

This is the javascript.

```
header .logo{


float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
}

header .topnav{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header .topnav a{
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .topnav a:not(:last-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    display: inline-block;
      float: right;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav .responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav .responsive .icon {
    float: right;
  }
  .topnav .responsive a{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

The CSS

I would appreciate it if you help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Some } brackets in your css are missing. But it is not answer)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you don't set the visibility of the links if .topnav gets responsive applied...

so something like:

```
.topnav.responsive a {
  display:block;
}
```

inside:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
...
}
```

here a working jsbin ;)
http://jsbin.com/vupizuyeji/edit?html,css,js,output

Cheerio :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I copied the the .topnav .responsive a from the jsbin but it still says that that "javascript:void(0);" at the bottom of the screen when I click it it says http://imgur.com/rl2xEr7. Here is the full code [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/wesepolaki/1/edit?html,css,js)

Comment: ur selector is wrong: .topnav .responsive a{ - the space between .topnav and .responsive...  
you want something with class .topnav AND class .responsive...  
easy to find by using the browser debugger ;)  
pls check the docs for further info ;)  
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html  
and here an updated js bin:  
http://jsbin.com/neqiguqobe/edit?html,css,output